# Need help converting list into a string when parsing Fasta file. Python

Tags: python-3.x

gene_finder() is suppose to take
the name of a file that contains a DNA sequence, reads that sequence from the file, identifies ORFs
in that sequence longer than min_len (a number), with %GC content over minGC (a fraction),
and, for each ORF above the minimum requirements, returns a list of its length, its %GC content,
and the DNA sequence itself. If there is more than one ORF, this should be a list of lists.

```
def get_orf(DNA):
    codon = ''
    if(DNA[0:3] == 'ATG'):
        codon = DNA[0:3]
        for x in range(3,len(DNA)+1,3):
            if DNA[x:x+3] == "TAG"  or DNA[x:x+3] == "TAA" or DNA[x:x+3] == "TGA":
                return codon
            else: codon = codon + DNA[x:x+3] 

    if codon[-3:] in ["TAG", "TAA", "TGA"]:
        return codon
    else: 
        return 'No ORF'  

def one_frame(DNA):
    x = 0
    ORFlist = []

    while x < len(DNA):
        codon = DNA[x:]
        if codon.startswith('ATG'):
            ORF = get_orf(DNA[x:])
            if ORF:
                ORFlist.append(ORF)
            x += len(ORF)
        else: 
            x += 3

    return(ORFlist)

def find_all_orfs(DNA):
    ORFlist = []
    x = one_frame(DNA)
    b = one_frame(DNA[1:])
    c = one_frame(DNA[2:])

    ORFlist = x+b+c

    return ORFlist

def gene_finder(file_name, min_len, minGC):
    x = open(file_name)
    contents = x.readlines()
    GCCount = 0
    ORFlen = []
    GCContent = []
    while contents.len > min_len:
        ORF = one_frame(contents)
        ORFlen.append(len(ORF))   
        for x in contents:
            if x == 'G' or x == 'C':
                GCCount += ((x/len(contents))*100)
                GCContent.append(GCCount)
    x.close

    return ORFlen, GCContent, contents
```

Everything else seems to work well. The gene_finder() function is what I am having problems with. I am fairly new to coding in python and in general. I am not necessarily an expert in reading and parsing fasta files. Whenever I call the function in the console, I get this error: 'AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'replace''. I know it is because that when I open the fasta file, it gives me a list. How do I convert that list into a string.

Answer (score 1):

You should use string method `.join(iterable)`.

It must be called on a string which will be your separator, since lists are iterables, you can convert a list into a string effortlessly:

```
>>> data = ["A", "B", "C"]
>>> ",".join(data)
'A,B,C'
```

For your particular case, separator would be `""` (empty string), which would turn `["A", "B", "C"]` into `"ABC"`.

You haven't really shown or explained where you get this error so I can't tell more than that, you don't call `.replace()` anywhere in the code you provided.

EDIT: If you ever need to convert a list that isn't strings into a string, e.g. `[1, 2, 3]` to get `"123"`, you must convert every element to string first, best way would probably be `data = [str(item) for item in data]`, now data contains strings and you can `.join()` it as you wanted. This list with a loop in it is called [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).